# If statement error when creating a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to see if a sheet exists and if so, place a new sheet after the specified sheet in the if statement.

The problem is it creates my new sheet successfully, but then it will try to create additional sheets IE: Sheet5,6,7 ETC. The error says the sheet already exists. Like it's still trying to run the code after it creates the new one.

```
    
    For Each ws In mybook.Worksheets
        
        If ws.Name = ("Sheet1") Then
        mybook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "My New Sheet"

        
        ElseIf ws.Name = ("Sheet2") Then
        mybook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet2")).Name = "My New Sheet"
        
        
        ElseIf ws.Name = ("Sheet3") Then
        mybook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet3")).Name = "My New Sheet"
        
        
        ElseIf ws.Name = ("Sheet4") Then
        mybook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet4")).Name = "My New Sheet"
        
        End If
    Next ws

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
For Each ws In mybook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = ("Sheet1") Or ws.Name = ("Sheet2") Or _
       ws.Name = ("Sheet3") Or ws.Name = ("Sheet4") Then

        mybook.Sheets.Add(After:=ws).Name = "My New Sheet"
        Exit For '<< done checking so exit the loop
  
    End If
Next ws
```

or this if you want to search for sheets in a specific order:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, arrSheets, s

arrSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")

For Each s In arrSheets
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = mybook.Worksheets(s)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        mybook.Sheets.Add(After:=ws).Name = "My New Sheet"
        Exit For '<< done checking so exit the loop
    End If

Next s
```

Comment: I tried it but it just added the page at the end even though the other sheets were present.

Comment: Works for me - in a workbook with those 4 sheets it adds a new sheet right after Sheet1 and then exits the loop

Comment: It works, but if  I move Sheet2 tab before Sheet1 it puts the new sheet before 1 instead of after.

Comment: OK it's not clear from your question exactly what you want.  Are you saying you want to check in turn for each of those sheets (1,2,3,4 in that order) and add the new sheet after the first one found?  So if 1 does not exists, add after 2, else 3, else 4 ?